# In a function with two lambdas, when used with .call, how come only the last lambda is evaluated? (ruby clojures)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lambda, closures, proc

In the following code, I was reading on closures, but wondered what would happen if there was more than one proc object in the function. So when the function was .called, only the last lambda was called.. I tested this below. (interactive: http://labs.codecademy.com/BAZX#:workspace)

```
def n_times(thing)
  lambda {|n| puts "first called"; thing * n}  
  lambda {|n| puts "second called"; thing - n}
end

test = n_times(2)
puts test.call(3)
```

How come the first lambda is skipped?

```
puts n_times(3).call(2) => second called 1
```

Moreso, why is the following invalid?
Edit: Removed, silly mistake. Thanks below :)

Comment: It's difficult to answer questions like this without understanding why you think the first lambda should be called, or why you think the second example should be valid. Like what did you expect the second example to do? What did you think it meant when you put the pipes around it?

Comment: The reason I tested this, is because .call doesnt really take parameters besides passing args to a block. But I don't know what lambda .call chooses to execute. I wanted to test if it executed both blocks so I used put statements to see if the code of the first was at least executed, but it wasn't. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1):

A lambda is a closure, meaning the code inside it does not run until the lambda is called. You create the first lambda, but none of the code in the block is executed until you do lambda.call.

The last lambda is returned, so it is what is called. Here's a little timeline of execution:

```
test = n_times(2)
puts test.call(3)
```

1. n_times called (2 passed in)
2. lambda 1 created in the scope of n_times
3. lambda 2 created "
4. lambda 2 is implicitly returned (last value), stored in `test`
5. `test.call(5)` - the 2nd lambda is called with 5 passed in
6. "second called" is printed, and -1 is returned

---

*No longer relevant:*

```
lambda {|t| puts |t|}
```

should be

```
lambda {|t| puts t}
```

Comment: I thought this, thats why I put in a puts statement in the first lambda, even if it wasn't the one being returned it should have still printed to the console no?